# Android WebView -> how to set name?

Tags: java, android, webview

In vanilla JavaFX, the programmer can do the following:

```
JSObject window = (JSObject) getWebEngine().executeScript("window");
window.setMember("app", myJavaFXApp);
```

Unless I am horribly mistaken, I see that I am able to set Client in Android WebView with:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(myJavaFXApp);
```

However, this will not do, because it does not know that the HTML pages refer to `myJavaFXApp` as `"app"`.

How do I achieve the exact same effect as written in JavaFX in Android?